# Would repeatedly allocate a char array in dynamic lead to problems?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

Pseudo code in C++

```
char* data = new char[determine_size()];
// ... do some stuff with data
delete[] data;
// ... repeat process
```

So basically, data gets repeatedly allocated to a new array with a different size each time. Though every time the previous allocation would always be de-allocated first.

Would this lead to memory fragmentation?

I'm not very familiar with memory managing in C++; my gut feeling tells me this is not a good idea.

Comment: It depends.  Do you do any other allocations between the allocation of this data and the deletion of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask,

> “Would this lead to memory fragmentation?”

Well memory allocation is *necessary* for fragmentation to occur, but it is not *sufficient*.

I.e. **it depends**, on a lot of things, including the pattern of allocations, and the memory manager.

So as stated the question is really unanswerable.

But some good advice can still be given.

**Do not use raw arrays and `new`, use instead e.g. `std::vector` and `std::string`.**